# Implementation Standard for C# code? Does it exist?

Tags: c#, class, standards

I've recently been tasked with pulling together 4 independent developers at my company into a  cohesive team that generates similar (and good) code as a team.

We're implementing the use of iDesigns C# [coding standard](http://www.sourceformat.com/pdf/cs-coding-standard-idesign.pdf) which will help our code look similar, and does give some implementation guidelines, but is there a general standard, rules of thumb (Top 10) out there for how code should be built, what every class should 'have' or 'do'?

I read [this article by John Connelly](http://www.codehustle.com/2011/06/implementation-practices-10-things-you-should-do-to-every-c-class-that-you-write.html) about implementation practices, but am not having much luck in finding more references on the subject.

Is there a Implementation 'standard' out there for c# classes/projects? or is it such a broad subject that it can't be defined?

Comment: unifying code styles and formatting is a good first step towards improving readability, consistency, and thus indirectly, quality. Regarding "implementation practices" - without more information about your specific project, there's little point in enumerating "standard practices", since guidance is only effective when applied to more concrete problems/projects

Comment: Voting as non-constructive here, but look on [programmers.se] and you may find a similar question. Otherwise, ask it there.

Comment: Also, note that your iDesign link is seven years old...

Comment: Thanks John, I didn't realize there was a Programmers Stack exchange site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favorites:

- http://csharpguidelines.codeplex.com/releases/view/46280
- Microsoft's [Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

### [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/)

Although it isn't a standard as such, I'd strongly recommend considering the use of [`StyleCop`](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/). It's a highly customizable Visual Studio plugin that allows you to easily enforce coding standards. Additionally it can be integrated into your cruise control server build, so that if any of those standards aren't adhered to, it breaks the build.

A very useful little tool, that at first I hated, but now I love.

Answer (score 0):

The only C# standard C# has is the ["Standard ECMA-334 C# Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm)". Anything beyond that is up to the developer to do as they wish as they code their program.

Now there are some good rules of thumb to follow (like the two you referenced) but they are just rules of thumb. As long has the entire team is ***consistent*** with each other you can do whatever you want as a "standard".